# Rails - Ill effects of HABTM and has_many through used together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an association,

```
Shop habtm Products
Product habtm Shops

Shop belongs_to Merchant
```

For convenience, I also declared a

```
Merchant has_many :products, :through=>:shops
```

In my products controller,

`@products = current_user.merchant.products`

When I `<%=debug @products %>`, the collection includes multiple copies of the same object.

Is this normal or have I screwed myself by declaring HABTM and has_many through together?

If this is normal, is there a way to call the products without duplicate entries appearing?

Thank you.

**Update**

I realized this should be okay because the `habtm` is between `Shops` and `Products`. The `Merchant has_many Products`. Is it possible to call something like a `product.merchant` without setting a foreign key inside the product model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour if your merchant has some shops that offer the same product.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Sorry to finish up, is it possible to call the reverse `product.merchant`? Essentially, it's like the real world. Merchant has many shops and many products, but 1 product model belongs to one merchant only.

Comment: You can define `Product has_many :merchants, :through=>:shops`. Then you will end up with a list of merchants on `product.merchants` that should contain the same merchant (maybe multiple times). But this only works if you ensure that all merchants are selling their own products only. I would suggest adding another relation `Product belongs_to :merchant` even if it is a bit redundant. Then you can call `product.merchant`.

Comment: But in the last case, I would have to set a foreign_key inside Product model? I find that redundant as well. The product => merchant relationship should be defined already (though not strictly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct`:

```
@products = current_user.merchant.products.distinct(:product_id)
```

Comment: distinct to do on SQL. `uniq` do it in ruby. You change the SQL with distinct. Not with `uniq`